# Is it permissible to listen to something while tying tzitzit?

Tags: mitzvah, tzitzis, kavana-concentration

Let's be real: Tying tzitzit on a beged takes a long time. It's also a big mitzvah that enables an even bigger mitzvah every day. So is it appropriate to listen to something for entertainment — a shiur? a non-Torah talk show? religious music? non-religious music? — while you're tying? Or does that prevent proper kavanah?

Comment: Note that kavana isnt necessarily a requirement for tying tsitsit. Rambam writes in Hilkhot Tsitsit [1:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/2401.htm) that if one tied tsitsi without kavana it is kosher. The Shulhan Arukh (OH 14:2) writes that optimally one should be stringent to have tsitsit tied lishma, but if not, he can rely on Rambam.